# How do i schedule Azure Machine learning web service in Azure Scheduler?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-scheduler, azure-machine-learning-service

I have published the web service from Azure Machine Learning experiment and now i want this web service to be scheduled using Azure Scheduler

Can somebody please state the procedure?

I got the API KEY, REQUEST/RESPONSE and Batch Execution URI from the web service homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to first create a new job in the Azure management portal (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495651.aspx), where you can configure the URL and the HTTP method to POST, and specify the body. However, the initial configuration screens don't let you add any headers, so once you have created the job, go in and edit it to add the following headers:

Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer

This will work, but am wondering if this actually serves your purpose. If you're calling the synchronous (request response) endpoint of the AzureML service, you need to specify the inputs in the request payload, which is statically configured with the Azure Scheduler job. So you will effectively be repeating the same call over and over again. You may also want to explore [Azure Data Factory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) if your needs are served by calling the asynchronous (batch) endpoint of the AzureML service.